# Scaling an incrementing counter in MySQL (for keeping track of pageviews)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization, scalability

I have an integer MySQL column that is incremented each time a page is viewed. The SQL query looks something like this:

`UPDATE page SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = $id`

We began to run into scaling problems when the same page (same id) was viewed many times per second (record would lock in MySQL) and the query would grind MySQL to a halt. To combat this we've been using the following strategy:

Each time the  page loads we increment a counter in Memcache and put a job in a queue (Gearman) that would update the counter in MySQL in the background (amongst 3 worker machines). The simplified code looks like this:

On page view:

```
$memcache->increment("page_view:$id");
$gearman->doBackground('page_view', json_encode(array('id' => $id)));
```

In the background worker:

```
$payload = json_decode($payload);
$views = $memcache->get("page_view:{$payload->id}");
if (!empty($views)) {
    $mysql->query("UPDATE page SET views = views + $views WHERE id = {$payload->id}");
    $memcache->delete("page_view:{$payload->id}");
}
```

This has worked well. It allows us to cut down on the queries to the DB (as we aggregate the views in memcache before writing to the DB) and the DB write occurs in the background, not holding up the page load.

Unfortunately, we are starting to see MySQL locks again. It seems that very active pages are still getting ran at nearly the same time, causing MySQL to lock again. The locks are slowing down the writes and often kill our workers. This is causing the queue to grow very large, often having 70k+ jobs that are "behind"

My question: What's should we do next to scale this?

Comment: Something else to consider.  There may be a race condition between your `get` and `delete` memcache calls, resulting in loss of some counts on a loaded system.

Comment: which engine are you using, MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: @JoaquinCuencaAbela InnoDB

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about Gearman, so I may be wrong.

You're enqueueing a gearman task each time you increment the counter. I guess that it would be better to enqueue a task only if the result of `$memcache->increment` is 1. My rationale is that when the next update will arrive after the gearman task clears `page_view:$i`, you will not have a long queue of gearman tasks eager to update this new value in the DB. This should make your code independent of your update rate, and capped at how fast gearman picks new tasks (which will be, hopefully, slow enough). In a perfect world you could just ask gearman to delay this task ~1s. This will ensure that you only update this counter at a rate of 1 qps.

Independently of gearman, if you can accept slower READs and assuming you're using InnoDB, you can shard this counter.

To do that just add a shard column and make it part of the primary key, like

```
CREATE TABLE page (
     id INTEGER,
     shard INTEGER,
     views INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY (id, shard)
)
```

When you update this counter, choose randomly a shard between 1 - 10. When you read it, SUM over all shards of the `id` that you want to read. This will make reads 10x slower, but it will allow you to scale 10x on writes. (Of course it doesn't need to be 10, you can pick any number that you want.)

Comment: I actually did the first step. I'm only only queuing the job if the a view number was not in memcache. The shard column is an interesting idea. Looking into it now (wonder if we should just have a page_view_count table)...

Comment: @mmmattax if you have more stuff in this table, I guess you should split it. FWIW, when I had to deal with this problem I had to move the counters outside of MySQL, into a super simple in-memory daemon in C that have a simple HTTP interface. My ids were dense, so I could just allocate a big mmap'ed array to hold all the counters, synced to disk every 1s (nowadays I would use redis). It was in Panoramio, after we got acquired by Google. The YouTube guys used a statistical approach: beyond a limit, they only store a 1/N of all the views, and they add N to the counter with each hit.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you are using page counts for and how essential it is that all of them get recorded. Perhaps you could cache the counts in memory on each server then only persist them on some fixed schedule. That way you would control the number of accesses you have to the database.

Granted this obviously won't guarantee that the counts get persisted in the event the server goes down for any reason.  So, if it's for any important audit logging or anything where losing some of the page views would be a problem this won't work.

Comment: We display them in "real-time" to our users. We already are storing them in memory and writing them in the background via a job/message queue.

Comment: Ah gotcha. From what I understood I thought you were caching the value but still triggering a call to the database asynchronously with each page hit. My thought was persist the counts every minute or every 30 seconds rather than persisting for each hit.

Comment: Are the total page views also cached in memcached?  If not, have the total views cached in memcached and periodically written to backing storage.  When served to the user there is no db hit.

Comment: @AustinPhillips kind of hit the nail on the head with what I was suggesting. Basically it would be storing in memory and then persisting later such that the number of hits to the DB isn't tied to the number of page hits. Instead you have complete control over how frequent they are with your scheduling of the job that persists them.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's `INSERT DELAYED....` insert statement. It will not lock and will write when it can.

Comment: I'm doing an UPDATE statement, but I'll look into LOW_PRIORITY mode.

Comment: Scratch that, LOW_PRIORITY looks like a really bad option considering how busy this table is.

Comment: My apologies. I simply missed that it was an update. Unfortunately I cannot be of any more help right now. I'm just not able to think of a good solution (or of a good reason to have to show real-time page hits in this manner, either).

I'm going to ponder the issue, but it seems you 'll always run into issues with locks/reads -- probably even if you can get single row-locking.